# PHP/SQL sign-up form is not working

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to create a sign-up form for my website but my sql query returns the error

```
$sql failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''username','password','forename','surname','title') VALUES ('f','f','f','f','f')' at line 1
```

this is my code in signupaction.php:

```
<?php 
include('connect.php');
$username=$_POST["forename"];
$password=$_POST["surname"];
$forename=$_POST["username"];
$surname=$_POST["password"];
$title=$_POST["title"];
$sql = "INSERT INTO users ('username','password','forename','surname','title') VALUES ('$username','$password','$forename','$surname','$title')";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $link)  or exit('$sql failed: '.mysql_error());
echo($result);
?>
```

I have no idea why this isn't working, any advice would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to wrap the names of the fields with single quotes. You could possibly leave then as is or use back ticks. Using quotes makes mysql think you are dealing with strings.

Try something like this -

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (username,password,forename,surname,title) VALUES  
        ('$username','$password','$forename','$surname','$title')";
```

Comment: @njk - I'm assuming that the OP is dealing with the sanitization of the data before inserting it into the database - it's not really what this question is about.

Comment: @Lix Clearly OP is not given the code above. You should suggest prepared statements using `mysqli_` or `PDO`.

Comment: @njk - but you have already (very correctly) suggested that to him in a comment - also that doesn't answer the question at all.

Answer (score 0):

Don't quote the field names in the first set of parens in the SQL statement.

And switch to mysqli!  Make your life easier.